Flutter WMS Map Rendering is Slow Compared to Ionic: Alternative Solutions?
I am developing a Flutter application that displays layers published via GeoServer. I use WMS for this purpose. However, the rendering is very slow, and after some navigation on the map, the layers stop displaying altogether.
When I use the same layers in an Ionic application, I do not encounter any performance issues.
Here is my Flutter code:
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: FlutterMap(
    options: MapOptions(
      initialCenter: LatLng(39.93528, 32.82633),
      initialZoom: 16,
    ),
    children: [
      TileLayer(
        urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      ),
      TileLayer(
        wmsOptions: WMSTileLayerOptions(
          transparent: true,
          baseUrl: 'https://xxx.xxx.com/geoserver/mobil/wms?',
          layers: ['Bina', 'Kurum', 'Kampus'],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
);

